# How to loop thru an object from API and store it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, object

I fetched data from [this API](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo) and I would like to store certain things into State or a variable (as an array).

```
  var baseUrl = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=IBM&apikey=<api_key>`;

  const [chart, setChart] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {

      axios.get(baseUrl).then(res => {
          setChart(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
      });

  }, [baseUrl]);

  useEffect(()=>{}, [chart]);
```

At this point, chart (state) has all the data stored ( 100 entries ).

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-05-06",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2022-05-06": {
            "1. open": "135.4700",
            "2. high": "137.9900",
            "3. low": "135.4700",
            "4. close": "137.6700",
            "5. volume": "7306396"
        },
        "2022-05-05": {
            "1. open": "136.4600",
            "2. high": "137.2600",
            "3. low": "134.7600",
            "4. close": "135.9200",
            "5. volume": "5957434"
        },
```

Next, I would like to access "Time Series (Daily)" and get the "1. open" number for each day.

I tried to manually access that data like so ( just to see if it's working )

```
const getNumber = Object.keys(chart['Time Series (Daily)']["2022-05-06"]["1. open"]);
```

`console.log("today's 1.open number is: " + getNumber);`

but no.. react is very angry at me giving me an error saying:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Time Series (Daily)')"

I also tried without Object.keys but it's giving me the same error unfortunately. What's the problem ? How can I access that data and store it into state/let/const.

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of enumerable keys of the passed object. I do not see any use of it in your current code. To get the value `chart['Time Series (Daily)']["2022-05-06"]["1. open"]` would be used. Also your error indicates that `chart` is `undefined` at the point your are trying to access it.

Comment: Hi Matt, just a quick note, don't add your API Keys to public places... someone may get a hold of it and abuse it

Comment: console.log(Object.values(res['Time Series (Daily)']).map( i => i['1. open']));

Comment: @CraigWayne I was able to console log all entries using your and Georgy's answers.. instead of res I ran chart?. and boom, it worked.. I appreciate you taking time to help - I've been trying to figure this out for a few days.. Thank you Craig  wish you all the best

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need `Object.keys`. And the error you are getting is because you are calling `chart` before you assign it by calling `setChart`.
You should check if `chart` is not `undefined`, and it's better to check all properties you are accessing.

In that case for the first render you will get `undefined` (because you don't get data from the API yet) and then you will get the correct result.

```
const getNumber = chart?.['Time Series (Daily)']?.["2022-05-06"]?.["1. open"]
```

Comment: Ooooo I was able to fetch it with your code!!! THANK YOU! What does ?. do ?

Comment: @MattSzumilo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining